Why do Spanish dialects sound so close to Spanish?
Spanish dialects sound very close to Spanish from Spain. From what I could find, a lot of Spanish dialects sound very close to Spanish accent, even Basque a totally unrelated language sound like Spanish speaking Basque words. Galician sounds like a Spanish speaking Portuguese.
This isn't the case with German or Italian dialects, they usually sound very different. Is there a particular reason to it?

I’m not quite sure what you’re asking here. Spanish dialects sound like Spanish because they are Spanish. Are you asking why there’s relatively little phonetic variation between Spanish dialects as compared to some other languages? ’Cause I wouldn’t necessarily say that’s true. Chilean Spanish sounds very different from Andalusian, for example. But it is true that dialects of Spanish (and Spanish-adjacent languages like Catalan and even unrelated Basque) have more similar phonetic inventories than, say, dialects of English, where vowels especially vary wildly.

Yes I'm mainly talking about Spanish-adjacent languages like Catalan and even unrelated Basque). From the little Basque, or Catalan I heard it did sound more similar to the  Spanish spoken in Spain than say Mexican Spanish. I wonder if there is some influence from the  Spanish  pronunciation, or ist it a spontaneous trait? Do French Basque speakers speak Basque with a French accent?

Mutual influence is basically expected in such a scenario, just a question of degree.  For example English:Celtic, French:Celtic, Latin:Etruscan, Hindi:Dravidian, Mexican Spanish:Nahuatl...

Spanish like English is one language with lots of regional variations. Basque is 100% percent different from Spanish and in fact from any other European language. Linguists really do not know where it came from originally. Sure, Galician sounds like a Spanish person speaking Iberian Portuguese because it has equal elements of both but is in fact a separate language.

Can you say what you mean by 'dialects', please? To me even 'variants' always sound like their ancestral tongues.
If you ignore accents, English still sounds not unlike the Germanic language which gave birth to it after what? More than 1,000 years, anyway.
To foreigners, Spanish itself still sounds not greatly unlike Latin… as do French and Italian, Portuguese and all the other Romance tongues.
Unless you have a special idea of a 'dialect', why would any 'dialect' not broadly resemble the sound of its  parent tongue?

This is perhaps based on a personal feeling, which we may not share with you. From my point of view, every language sounds different. I don't really know German, but different dialects of Italian or Spanish sound similar to me. When studying foreign but similar languages ​​(e.g. Spanish x Portuguese, or Czech x Polish), this "melody" of the language helps students use the language correctly. If they does not follow this, they may end up in a situation where they does not know if they are not accidentally dragging constructs from the first language into the second language. Languages ​​developed in spoken form, not in writing or in the laboratories of linguists. The children listened to the language.
So if you feel that you hear significant differences in languages ​​such as German or Italian, it is possible that your brain can process the "melodies" of individual dialects much better than mine.
And if we were to admit that there is a difference in these two languages ​​compared to Spanish, then it could be the historical development of these territories. While today's Germany and Italy have been broken up into small territories several times in history, Spain has been covered by large state units throughout history. This means that in Spain people could communicate with each other and build a common "melody" much better than in fragmented Italy or Germany. I remember from history that at one time the German tribes were very much at odds. It is therefore possible that they communicated less with each other and therefore different melodies were created within individual dialects. In addition, Germanic peoples are generally less communicative and more closed in on themselves. The development of the German language could thus be dictated more by the state and other structures such as the church, rather than being created through common oral communication.
